create a file using a here-document command inside bash script
How can I create a file using the cat command with a here-document inside shell script"
#!/bin/bash

create_file () {
    cat > a.txt << EOF
    0 abc def 
    ghi jkl mno
    pqrs tuv wxyz
    EOF
}

create_file

Error
Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "}")


The EOF marker must be at the start of the line and can't be indented.

Use cat > a.txt <<- EOF (additional minus sign) and indent all until and inclusive EOF with tabs.

@JoachimSauer Wrong. see my other comment.

remove indentation after opening EOF:
#!/bin/bash

create_file () {
    cat > a.txt <<EOF
0 abc def 
ghi jkl mno
pqrs tuv wxyz
EOF
}

create_file

Bash looks for the same "delimiter" that you started with. You started with "EOF", but was ending with "____EOF" when using indentation, so it couldn't match closing delimiter
if you want add spacing for the resulting text, add indentation to the text, but keep EOF at the start of the line:
#!/bin/bash

create_file () {
    cat > a.txt <<EOF
  0 abc def 
  ghi jkl mno
  pqrs tuv wxyz
EOF
}

create_file



The line that ends the here doc must exactly match the string that you specify at the start of the here doc. So you can indent your code legibly do the following:

Add 4 blanks indentation to the opening string so it exactly matches the content of the closing line.
Indent the content of the here doc by a tab just to make it clearer what's inside the here-doc.
Add - after << to tell bash to ignore leading tabs (and only tabs, not all white space) in the here-doc:


#!/bin/bash

create_file () {
    cat > a.txt <<- '    EOF'
        0 abc def 
        ghi jkl mno
        pqrs tuv wxyz
    EOF
}

create_file

So the above here-doc with the important white-space spelled out is:
cat > a.txt <<- '<blank><blank><blank><blank>EOF'
<tab>0 abc def 
<tab>ghi jkl mno
<tab>pqrs tuv wxyz
<blank><blank><blank><blank>EOF

and it'll create this file with no leading white space:
0 abc def 
ghi jkl mno
pqrs tuv wxyz

If you want leading blanks in the output file then put them after any tabs in there here-doc:
cat > a.txt <<- '<blank><blank><blank><blank>EOF'
<tab><blank><blank>0 abc def 
<tab><blank><blank>ghi jkl mno
<tab><blank><blank>pqrs tuv wxyz
<blank><blank><blank><blank>EOF

If you want leading tabs in the output file then don't add - to the here-doc start construct << and do indent the here-doc contents with tabs and/or other white spaces exactly as you want it to appear in the output:
cat > a.txt << '<blank><blank><blank><blank>EOF'
<tab>0 abc def 
<tab>ghi jkl mno
<tab>pqrs tuv wxyz
<blank><blank><blank><blank>EOF

If you copy/paste the above and it outputs a file with leading white space it's because you forgot to convert the blanks that this site shows inside the here-doc to tabs for your real code.
